# SQL: Select the Running Total of Column C for pairwise combinations of two other columns A and B

Tags: sql, hive, presto, aggregator

I'm trying to query a table and calculate the running sum of a column's values for pairwise combinations of two other columns.

Specifically, given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
bucket int(10) NOT NULL,
label varchar(10) NOT NULL,
amount int(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, "A", 1),
(1, "B", 2),
(1, "C", 3),
(2, "A", 4),
(2, "B", 5),
(2, "C", 6),
(3, "A", 7),
(3, "B", 8),
(3, "C", 9),
(4, "A", 10),
(4, "B", 11),
(4, "C", 12);
```

I want to query a column that calculates the cumulative sum for each bucket/label pair.

Put another way, I want to be able to write a query that selects bucket, label, and a third column that's the cumulative sum of the "amount" column for every entry with a label that matches that row's label. For example, for the above example, the third column should have the values:

```
1, 
2, 
3, 
5, 
7, 
9, 
12, 
15, 
18, 
22, 
26, 
30
```

In other words, the value 5 is the sum of 1 and 4 (the first two amounts for the "A" label), the value 7 is the sum of 2 and 5 (the first two amounts of the "B" label), etc.

I know I can get the cumulative sum for the entire column by doing something like:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (
        ORDER BY amount
    ) AS running_total
FROM test
```

but I'm not sure how to split it up by label.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `partition by` clause:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY label 
                         ORDER BY amount
                        ) AS running_total
FROM test t
ORDER BY bucket, amount;
```

Although `ORDER BY amount` works for your data, I think you might really want the bucket as well:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY label 
                         ORDER BY bucket, amount
                        ) AS running_total
FROM test t
ORDER BY bucket, amount;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9b7530d306c35ed6e7ea4b90cc7e813) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that this uses MySQL 8, because your create/insert code is compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how elegant this is, nor did you specify which SQL engine you are using. But here is a solution for PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (
        ORDER BY amount
    ) AS running_total,
    (SELECT SUM (amount) AS bucket_total 
        FROM test AS inner_test 
        WHERE inner_test.label = outer_test.label 
        AND inner_test.amount <= outer_test.amount)
FROM test AS outer_test
```

Basically, it sums up the amounts of the inner select that have the same label and the same or lesser amounts as the outer select.

**Edit**: I am leaving this answer here for reference, but the superior way to do this is @Gordon Linoff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441870/6150775).

Comment: I get the answer, but even in Postgres this isn't the best solution, so I don't get the upvote.